# Get python project into docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm new to python. I have a maven project which uses the org.jolokia maven-docker-plugin to create a docker image that consumes a python library.

Currently the container uses a `pip install` to install the python library.

I have forked the python library and made some changes, and now I would like my docker container to consume **MY** version of the python library. How can I do this?

### What I have tried:

1. Copied my changed python file to overwrite the folder located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which was generated after pip install (via mount directory into container).
2. Created tar of entire python project, added it into image using fileSets, ran `pip install /maven/mypythonversion.tar.gz`.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a Dockerfile to define the container? If so could you show what you've tried there?

Comment: Yes, the Dockerfile just sets some irrelevant label information and has the lines 'COPY maven /maven/' `ENTRYPOINT ["/maven/startup.sh"]'. Startup.sh just executes the java application. But in order to get the tar / project folder into the container I used maven pom file with the docker-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to get your python project into the image and run `install` on the setup.py. This method assumes your image already has the python interpreter and the relevant dependencies installed for your project to run.

Copy your **python project code** into a **folder** in your **maven project** i.e. one called `input`.

Use **fileSets** in the **assembly** of the image to assemble the python source code into the image. `<directory>` should point to the input folder containing your python source code:

```
<assembly>
    <mode>tar</mode>
    <inline>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>C:/.../input</directory>
                <outputDirectory>/output</outputDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
    </inline>
</assembly>
```

Then you want a script to run `python setup.py install` from the output directory (`/maven/output/mypythonproject`).

I.e. use a runCmd:

```
<runCmds>
    <run>
        cd /maven/output/mypythonproject \
        python setup.py install
    </run>
</runCmds>
```

This installs the python module and puts egg file in the `/usr/local/lib/python27/dist-packages` folder, which will be found by your python interpreter.